# How to use convert -crop to add more background to animated gif/enlarge image?

Tags: animation, imagemagick, transparency, gif

I'm trying to crop an animated gif usind `convert -crop`. In some cases it's necessary to add more background to the image to fit. With other image formats it's done with

```
convert original.gif -rotate 0 -crop 1519x759-237-61\! -background white -flatten edited.gif
```

For gifs I tried

```
convert original.gif -coalesce -rotate 0 -crop 1519x759-237-61\! +repage edited.gif
```

`convert` is clipping/trimming the background and just the "subject" of the image is shown.

Example is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpbTD.jpg

Result is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvtJI.jpg

Expected Result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQiYu.jpg

I added the red border to show how big the image is. Someone with a great solution? :)

Jan

Comment: This `convert` worked for me
```convert original.gif -coalesce -rotate 0 +repage -background none -extent 1519x759-237-61! edited.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want in Imagemagick, you should be using -extent rather than -crop in order to extend the size of the output.

Try this. Adjust the size and offset and background color as desired.

```
convert original.gif -coalesce -rotate 0 +repage -background white -extent 1519x759-237-61! -bordercolor red -border 3 result.gif
```

[image]

I have added a red border around the image.

Comment: Also a working and correct answer. I changed `-background white` to `-background none` to keep the transparency.

Comment: If you like both answers, you can upvote both of them. Mine answer was first, though.

Comment: I thougt I accepted the first answer. Upvotes are Not visible because I‘m new at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

With IM you can choose to "-crop", which is most often used to reduce the viewport dimensions, or "-extent", which can also be used to enlarge the viewport. It looks like there are a couple other issues with achieving the result in your sample image, but for starters, try simply substituting your "-crop" with "-extent" like this...

```
convert original.gif -coalesce -rotate 0 -extent 1519x759-237-61 +repage edited.gif
```

That will put your input image in a viewport of 1519x759, and place its upper left corner at 237 pixels from the left and 61 pixels from the top. You shouldn't need the exclamation point "!" in any case.

Comment: `-extent` did it.